# How to set image rendering in Points in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of HTML and using PT(Point) as a rendering unit. My HTML also has an image tag and Image height and width can vary. So, I can't apply any height and width to the image tag. But when it renders in browser treat it as (PX)pixel unit. But I want to browser to understand my complete HTML is in PT(point) unit. So, treat this also as Point. How can I achieve this?

I have created two js fiddle on using PX(https://jsfiddle.net/r18gasz6/1/) unit and other on PT(https://jsfiddle.net/r18gasz6/2/) unit. If we see PT unit JSFiddle font size, it looks bigger than the PX unit font size JSfiddle. I also want my Image to auto resize based on PT unit. But I don't know height and width in advance. So, can't apply on it. Please suggest if this can be achieve only through CSS only. Can't use any scripting also.

**HTML**

```
<div class="field txtleft">
                    <span class="field" id="6DATE1">2019-01-16</span>
                    <span class="field" id="6PLAC1">NOIDA, UTTAR PRADESH</span>
                    <div id="6SURL1"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQV-Q2JYmvV8h_5cIYJ6Czg4yqONKcgOsvOZFEjkRwsFkIeGk4T3w" alt=""></div>
                </div>
```

**CSS PX**

```
.field{  font-size:11px;}
```

**CSS PT**

```
.field{  font-size:11pt;}
```

---

**PX RESULT:**

(TEXT IS 11 PX)

[image: PX RESULT TEXT IS 11 PX]

---

**PT RESULT:**

(TEXT IS 11PT Looks bigger compare to 11px)

[image: PT RESULT AS TEXT IS 11PT Looks bigger compare to 11px]

---

Answer (score 0):

When compare to px and pt, 
The value of 1 pt to rem = 0.08333333333333333.
The value of 1 px to rem = 0.0625.

For example if you want to use pt inserted px 
**10px = 10pt**

check the doc for your [reference](http://pxtoem.com/)

[demo](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/GPLLGP) code below:

```
.field{  font-size:13px; }
.field1{  font-size:10pt;}
```

For your information.

Point values are only for print! A point is a unit of measurement used for real-life ink-on-paper typography. 72pts = one inch. One inch = one real-life inch like-on-a-ruler. Not an inch on a screen, which is totally arbitrary based on resolution. **Point (pt) is not recommended to use in web pages** since cross-browser results can be very different.